# Why is console.log working sometimes and not working other times?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am running the following code in a Javascript on vscode and sometimes it will log successfully to the console, sometimes it will not. I am a beginner and cannot work out the reason why this is happening. I'm willing to provide any other details you may need to figure this problem out. It always at least logs some of the parts, but usually not all.

```js
const arrayToList = (array) => {
    var list = null;
    for (i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        list = {
            value: array[i],
            rest: list
        }
    }
    return list
}


console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));


const listToArray = (list) => {
    var array = [];
    for (let node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
        array.push(node.value)
    }
    return array
}

console.log(listToArray(arrayToList([10, 20, 30])));

const prepend = (value, list) => {
    return {
        value, 
        rest: list
    };
}

console.log(prepend(10, prepend(20, null)));

const nth = (list, n) => {
    if (n == 0) {
        return list.value;
    } else {
        return nth(list.rest, n - 1);
    }
}

console.log(nth(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]), 0));
```

Comment: When it is not working?

Comment: Seems to be always working in the snippet

Comment: Just at random it does stuff like this: https://imgur.com/a/6ddkoL2